# Matlab: Plotting on two axes on different figures

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I have two figures

```
f1 = figure('visible','off');
f2 = figure('visible','off');
```

Now I want to get some data `[x1Array,y1Array]` & `[x2Array,y2Array]` and plot the first set on figure `f1` and the second set on figure `f2`.

I have tried using:

```
plot(f1,x1Array,y1Array);
plot(f2,x2Array,y2Array);
```

but this gives me an error: *Error using ==> plot String argument is an unknown option.*
I think this means that the handle is not what Matlab expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what data type has your data?

Comment: @thewaywewalk all integers

Comment: Are your arrays really arrays or are they vectors?

Comment: Are you trying to plot things in too separate figures or would creating subplots work for you?

Comment: @user3681614 arrays like x1array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; and I need them in separate figures. I've used two figures in my example but I'm actually using about 20 which wouldn't all fit on one figure as different subplots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', f1)
plot(x1Array, y1Array)
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', f2)
plot(x2Array, y2Array)
```

Comment: Or `figure(f1)` instead of `set(...)`

Comment: @LuisMendo's solution is more readable, but by doing `figure(handle),` it is essentially doing what Drake is suggesting.  Either way, either solution will solve the OP's question.